# How to fix problem of printing regional language text using text interpretation in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I am developing one component using Angular 7 and ASP .Net MVC. I am using text editor to store some data with styles and bullets and so on. I want to print that entered data into text editor, for that I am using format object property called "Text Interpretation" with HTML text value.
It works for me when I enters data into English language. If I am entering any regional language then it is not showing in crystal report.

I have set property to HTML text for Text Interpretation with font @Arial Unicode MS still it is not showing regional language text.

I expect the output should display as it is entered into text editor. Please let me know any solution on above problem, because I am very new in these technologies.
Thanking you in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Have a read of this, your issue is to do with character sets, not fonts: [link](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: can you change your font to `Tahoma` and try? @Mandar

Comment: @NijinKoderi it won't work for me.

Comment: @Mandar Arabic and all working fine with `tahoma`. that is why i told. let me try

Comment: @iakobski sir you was correct but not now I am not able to convert to html to pdf.

Comment: @NijinKoderi sir I am using Indian language to print some data.